# Addition jquery values outside the loop (create live bid)

Tags: jquery

I wish to use checkboxes and radios to create a live bid.

I have options and sub options.
If my option have subs option their values is "yes" if not there is a number (ex: 200, 300...)
Each sub options have values too.

In result I wish to add all options values checked is there is a number + sub options checked.

If the main option is unchecked the result of this one and it's children has to be substracted from the result.

I create some loops with checked status but I can't not use the variable outside their loops, this not working.

Some one knows how to resolve it?

```js
    
$(document).ready(function() {
    var id;
    
    $('.option input').each(function () { // hide / show sub options if the option is wished
        id = $(this).attr('name');
        $('.option input').change(function () {
            $( "."+this.name).toggleClass('hide');
        });
    });

     
        var basisPrice = $('.prixBaseSite').text() ;// price without options
        var tailorPrice= $('.prixMaxSite').text(); // price maximum to indicate "sur mesure text"
        var totalprice ;
        var valeur;
        var optionPrice;
        var totalOp;
        var sum;

    $('.cboxDevis').change(function () { // take the option value : if not sub options, takae the value, if has one take the value of their children checked
        
          $('.cboxDevis:checked').each(function(){     
              value = $(this).val();

                if($.isNumeric(valeur)){
                    optionPrice = valeur;                   
                }
                
          });     
          totalOp+=parseInt(optionPrice);
    });

       
    $('ul .switch').click(function() {  // take the option value if it's checked
        sum = 0;
        $('ul .switch:checked').each(function(idx, elm) {
            sum += parseInt(elm.value, 10);    
                        
        });    
    });

    totalprice = parseInt(basisPrice)+parseInt(totalOp)+parseInt(sum); 

    if(totalprice > tailorPrice){
        $('#prixSite p').html('Your service is more than <span class="prixTotal">'+tailorPrice+'€</span>' ); // replace html with the correct price
    }else{
        $('#prixSite p').html('Your service from <span class="prixTotal">'+totalprice+'€</span>' ); // replace html with the correct price
    }
 });
```

```css
ul.devisLi.hide{display:none;}
ul.devisLi{display:block;}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="col">            
    <div class="prixBaseSite" style="display:none;">1700€</div> <!-- Basis price -->
    <div class="prixMaxSite" style="display:none;">3000€</div> <!-- max price -->

    <div class="option">  <!-- option 1 -->
      <div class="titleO">
        <input id="pagesOui" type="checkbox" class="cboxDevis" value="oui" class="" name="pagesO"><label for="pagesOui" class=" p-3 mini-radius justify-content-between d-flex">Option 1 with subs<span class="cboxButon"></span></label>
      </div>
      <ul class="pagesO hide devisLi">
        <li class="m-2"><input id="pages1" type="radio" name="pages" class="switch" value="200" ><label for="pages1" ><span class="box"></span><span>5-10 items</span></label></li>
        <li class="m-2"><input id="pages2" type="radio" name="pages" class="switch" value="10000" ><label for="pages2" ><span class="box"></span><span>>10 items</span></label></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="option">  <!-- option 2 -->
      <div class="titleO">                                                  
        <input id="fct1" type="checkbox" class="cboxDevis" value="10000" class="" name="fct"><label for="fct1" class=" p-3 mini-radius justify-content-between d-flex">Option 2 without subs  <span class="cboxButon"></span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="option">  <!-- option 3 -->
      <div class="titleO">                                                  
        <input id="seo1" type="checkbox" class="cboxDevis" value="oui" class="" name="seo"><label for="seo1" class=" p-3 mini-radius justify-content-between d-flex">Option 3 with subs <span class="cboxButon"></span></label>
      </div>
        <ul class=" seo hide devisLi ">
          <li class="m-2"><input id="nbrpages1" type="radio" name="nbrpages" class="switch" value="250" ><label for="nbrpages1" ><span class="box"></span><span>5 items</span></label></li>
          <li class="m-2"><input id="nbrpages2" type="radio" name="nbrpages" class="switch" value="500" ><label for="nbrpages2" ><span class="box"></span><span>10 items</span></label></li>
          <li class="m-2"><input id="nbrpages3" type="radio" name="nbrpages" class="switch" value="10000" ><label for="nbrpages3" ><span class="box"></span><span>More than 10 items</span></label></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
   <div class="option">  <!-- option 4 -->
    <div class="titleO">                                                  
      <input id="blog1" type="checkbox" class="cboxDevis" value="200" class="" name="blog"><label for="blog1" class=" p-3 mini-radius justify-content-between d-flex">you need service 2 ?<span class="cboxButon"></span></label>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> <!-- end col --> 

  <div id="prixSite" style="background:#efefef" class="prixSite ">
    <p class="p-3 text-center"></p>
  </div> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to deal with every single checkbox/radio subs one by one and you trying to add/exclude its value .. But for me it'll be better to get all the values when checkbox/radio is checked/unchecked

This function should help to get the sum of checked checkboxs/radios

```
function Sum(){
  var sum = 0;    // set sum to 0
  $('.cboxDevis:checked').each(function(){  // loop through checked checkboxes
    $( "."+this.name).find('input:radio:checked').each(function(){ // get the checked radio
      sum += parseInt(this.value);  // add to sum
    });
  });
  console.log(sum);
}
```

See the next example .. And you can build on this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // change event for toggle the radios inputs  
  $('.option input.cboxDevis').on('change' ,function () {
    $( "."+this.name).toggleClass('hide');
  });
  // change event to get the sum using the Sum function
  $('.cboxDevis , .devisLi input:radio').on('change' , Sum);

});

function Sum(){
  var sum = 0;
  $('.cboxDevis:checked').each(function(){
    $( "."+this.name).find('input:radio:checked').each(function(){
      sum += parseInt(this.value);
    });
  });
  console.log(sum);
}
```

```css
ul.devisLi.hide{display:none;}
ul.devisLi{display:block;}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="col">            
    <div class="prixBaseSite" style="display:none;">1700€</div> <!-- Basis price -->
    <div class="prixMaxSite" style="display:none;">3000€</div> <!-- max price -->

    <div class="option">  <!-- option 1 -->
      <div class="titleO">
        <input id="pagesOui" type="checkbox" class="cboxDevis" value="oui" class="" name="pagesO"><label for="pagesOui" class=" p-3 mini-radius justify-content-between d-flex">Option 1 with subs<span class="cboxButon"></span></label>
      </div>
      <ul class="pagesO hide devisLi">
        <li class="m-2"><input id="pages1" type="radio" name="pages" class="switch" value="200" ><label for="pages1" ><span class="box"></span><span>5-10 items</span></label></li>
        <li class="m-2"><input id="pages2" type="radio" name="pages" class="switch" value="10000" ><label for="pages2" ><span class="box"></span><span>>10 items</span></label></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="option">  <!-- option 2 -->
      <div class="titleO">                                                  
        <input id="fct1" type="checkbox" class="cboxDevis" value="10000" class="" name="fct"><label for="fct1" class=" p-3 mini-radius justify-content-between d-flex">Option 2 without subs  <span class="cboxButon"></span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="option">  <!-- option 3 -->
      <div class="titleO">                                                  
        <input id="seo1" type="checkbox" class="cboxDevis" value="oui" class="" name="seo"><label for="seo1" class=" p-3 mini-radius justify-content-between d-flex">Option 3 with subs <span class="cboxButon"></span></label>
      </div>
        <ul class=" seo hide devisLi ">
          <li class="m-2"><input id="nbrpages1" type="radio" name="nbrpages" class="switch" value="250" ><label for="nbrpages1" ><span class="box"></span><span>5 items</span></label></li>
          <li class="m-2"><input id="nbrpages2" type="radio" name="nbrpages" class="switch" value="500" ><label for="nbrpages2" ><span class="box"></span><span>10 items</span></label></li>
          <li class="m-2"><input id="nbrpages3" type="radio" name="nbrpages" class="switch" value="10000" ><label for="nbrpages3" ><span class="box"></span><span>More than 10 items</span></label></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
   <div class="option">  <!-- option 4 -->
    <div class="titleO">                                                  
      <input id="blog1" type="checkbox" class="cboxDevis" value="200" class="" name="blog"><label for="blog1" class=" p-3 mini-radius justify-content-between d-flex">you need service 2 ?<span class="cboxButon"></span></label>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> <!-- end col --> 

  <div id="prixSite" style="background:#efefef" class="prixSite ">
    <p class="p-3 text-center"></p>
  </div> 
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late
Thanks a lot it's working ! :)